# Where to locate http logs subdirectory for Virtuoso?

Tags: virtuoso

I'm writing a java client that uploads a file to `Virtuoso WebDAV` repository through `HTTP PUT`.
There is a bug in my code I'm trying to fix. I want to check the log file for the `WebDAV` server as the bug is relating to HTTP connection reset.

I found the description of the WebDAV server configuration in the Virtuoso configuration file `virtuoso.ini`.

```
[HTTPServer]
ServerPort                  = 8890
ServerRoot                  = ../vsp
DavRoot                     = DAV
EnabledDavVSP               = 0
HTTPProxyEnabled            = 0
TempASPXDir                 = 0
DefaultMailServer           = localhost:25
MaxClientConnections        = 5
MaxKeepAlives               = 10
KeepAliveTimeout            = 10
MaxCachedProxyConnections   = 10
ProxyConnectionCacheTimeout = 15
HTTPThreadSize              = 280000
HttpPrintWarningsInOutput   = 0
Charset                     = UTF-8
;HTTPLogFile                 = logs/http.log
```

The last line tells the http log file should be `http.log` in the `logs` folder.

However, I searched all the places in the virtuoso installation directory, and no subdirectory called `logs` found in the directory.

I also tried the [Virtuoso online documentation](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksRecording), but it doesn't help.

I'm a new user of Virtuoso, and really do not have much knowledge of it. Hope someone can help with this.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't the fact that the last line starts with a semicolon mean that it is commented out? I suggest removing that and restarting Virtuoso.

Comment: That's correct.  All characters following unescaped-whitespace+semicolon (`;`) or unescaped-whitespace+hash ('#`) will be ignored. (Such whitespace may include newlines, spaces, tabs, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change to

```
HTTPLogFile = http.log
```

and it will create a file `http.log` in the same directory from where the virtuoso instance was started or where `virtuoso.ini` is located